# iPhone app update while still in background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I was wondering what happens if a user updates an app (through the app store/update) while the app is still in the background on iOS 4.x

I am planning a big update for my next release and I wanted to know if it is a special case I have to handle to avoid a crash.

Or can I trust the OS to restart the application on the next launch (or to kill the background process during the update), detecting that the application has changed instead of just doing a "applicationWillEnterForeground"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS / Apple take care of that use-case for you, you don't need to worry about it. Your app will get terminated, so when the user next taps its icon you will have a relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Any app in suspended in the iOS "background" can get terminated by the OS at any time.  The OS knows to do the "right thing" when the app's icon is tapped on again next.  An app update would just be another case of that same thing happening.